# AFrame and the camera motion - identical to the inspector

Tags: controls, aframe

I am interested in setting up an AFrame scene which has the exact same camera motion than the one we get when we invoke the 'Inspector (Ctrl+Alt+I)'.

- left click used to move the camera
- wheel for zooming
- right click moves with no rotations the camera

It is an equivalent set up that would be found in the CAD - CAO softwares like rhino for example.

For the moment I have this set up, which has not the wheel-zooming, and that is not natural:

```
    <a-entity look-at="#WorldFrame" look-controls>
        <a-entity position="7 0 -7" rotation="0 135 0">
            <a-camera fov="20" zoom="0.6" look-controls="enabled:false">
                <a-cursor></a-cursor>
            </a-camera>
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
```

Any clue?
thanks

EDIT:
the right configuration for the left-click seems to be the following:

```
    <a-entity id="cameraTarget" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" look-controls >
        <a-entity position="7 0 7" >
            <!-- Disable the default wasd controls we are using those to control the ship -->
            <a-camera id="cameraID" fov="20" zoom="0.6" look-controls="enabled:false">
                <a-cursor></a-cursor>
            </a-camera>
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
```

I still have no clue for the wheel and right click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aframe-orbit-controls](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/orbit-controls/)

```
<head>
  <title>My A-Frame Scene</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.2.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-supercraft-loader@1.1.3/dist/aframe-supercraft-loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-entity supercraft-loader="name: icky-snake"></a-entity>
    <a-entity camera look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 1.6 -0.5; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 180; initialPosition: 0 5 15"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate a lot your job. Thanks for your answer which solved the problem. By any chance do you know if it is possible to diminish the fish eye effect. I tried playing with the fov and zoom attribute, but they had no more effect?

Comment: Hmm, camera fov should do it. The default camera shouldn't have much fisheye. You did set it to 20 right?

Comment: yes 20. but seems to have no effect. Note that with your solution we are no longuer using a <a-camera> tag but an entity with camera component. does that make a difference?

Comment: I edited the answer for the fov to work, but the orbit-controls is lost wen going full screen on my computer.

Comment: the orbit control is broken in version 0.7.0, was working with 0.5.0.

Comment: I have updated with our own orbit controls https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/orbit-controls/